# Swift - Process.Launch getting different results than calling the same command in Terminal

Tags: json, swift, terminal, command-line-interface

I'm trying to integrate a CLI into a macOS Swift app.  Calling the command in Terminal results in valid json:

```
{
  "title": "SiteName",
  "version": 1,
...
```

But if I use the following code I get additional characters:

```
  let process = Process()
  let pipe = Pipe()
  process.arguments = arguments
  process.launchPath = "/usr/local/bin/op"
  process.launch()
    
  let data = pipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
  let output = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!
```

I've tried other variations, such as using process.Run instead of process.Launch.  All give the same results:

```
{
  [94m"title"[0m: [92m"SiteName"[0m,
  [94m"version"[0m: [93m1[0m,
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, I must have done something differently before, since process.Run is working for me now.

```
  let process = Process()
  let pipe = Pipe()
  process.standardError = pipe
  process.standardOutput = pipe
  process.executableURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/usr/local/bin/op"  
  process.standardInput = nil
  process.arguments = arguments
  try process.run()
    
  let data = pipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
  let output = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!
```